# How to develop extention for Sony Smartband Talk (SWR30)

Tags: sony-smartwatch

I've tried to start developing extentions for Sony's smartband SWR30, but failed to make any extention that would be visible in SmartBand Talk application (which is required to install extention on SWR30).

I've tried to use Sony's Guide for SmartWatch 2, change Registration class to be compatible with SWR30 (like width, height, etc). But still no result.

Finally I've looked into oryginal extentions that are installed together with SmartBand Talk application and find out there is used package com.sonymobile.smartwear.swr30 which I cannot find anywhere (Sony Add-On SDK does not include it). How can I get access to that API while on Google Play store there is already one extention that is not "made by" SonyMobile...

So simple question is how to start developing extentions for SWR30, what is required (SDKs ?).
Any simple "Hello World" guide is more than welcome.

Answer (score 2):

SmartBand Talk SDK has not been published publicly yet. It is available only to partners.

For details regarding partnership, you can contact through email.

You can find email address under "Other Developer Questions" section on this page:
http://developer.sonymobile.com/about/how-do-i-get-in-contact/